Text Animation Smooth in Chrome but Stuck and Not Smooth in Safari and iOS Devices
I'm working on a website with a text animation that looks smooth and performs well in Chrome. However, the same animation appears stuck and not smooth in Safari and on iOS devices.
Here's a brief overview of the setup:
The animation is applied to a h1 element using CSS keyframes.
I'm using -webkit-animation for Safari and iOS support.
The animation involves transforming and opacity changes.
CSS Code:
.hero-scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, top 0.7s ease, color 0.7s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes keyarm {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-14deg); }
  10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes keyarm {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  5% { transform: rotate(-14deg); }
  10% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1001;
  transition: top 0.7s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, color 0.7s ease;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-animation: keyarm 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: keyarm 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

React Component Code:
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const HeroSection = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <div className="hero-section">
            <div className="hero-image-left">
                <h1 className="hero-scroll" ref={ref}>ATNATIC</h1>
                <div className="video-container">
                    <video 
                        src="/Static/Models/Refercopy.mp4" 
                        autoPlay 
                        loop 
                        muted
                        playsInline
                        className="hero-video"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
});

export default HeroSection;

App.js

    const handleScroll = () => {
        const header = headerRef.current;
        const heroText = heroTextRef.current;
        const threshold = header ? header.offsetHeight : 0;
    
        if (header) {
            if (window.scrollY > threshold) {
                header.classList.add('visible');
                header.classList.remove('pre-scroll');
            } else {
                header.classList.remove('visible');
                header.classList.add('pre-scroll');
            }
        }
    
        if (heroText) {
            if (window.scrollY >= threshold) {
                heroText.classList.add('sticky');
            } else {
                heroText.classList.remove('sticky');
            }
        }
    };

Problem:
The animation works well in Chrome but is not smooth in Safari and iOS devices. It appears stuck or choppy.
What I've Tried:
Added -webkit- prefixes for better support in Safari.
Ensured the will-change property is set.
Verified the issue persists on different devices.
Any suggestions on how to make the animation smoother across all browsers, especially Safari and iOS devices?
Test Link:
[1]: https://atnatic.netlify.app

use this it might work:
.sticky { will-change: transform, opacity; } 
also try this:
.sticky { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(0, 0, 0); } 

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
